# ApplePay how to add cardholderName

Tags: ios, token, payment, applepay

In encrypted payment data for ApplePay, there is one optional keyword "cardholderName". We just get the token by the following code.

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {

    NSString *hexToken = payment.token.paymentData.hexadecimalString;
}
```

And the cardholderName is empty after decrypt this token. So how can we add this holder name to the token and from where can we get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As described in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929), `cardholderName` is an optional field that may not be passed back as part of the token. If it is blank you'll have to do without it.